# Dependency-Check report does not exist in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, sonarqube

I am new to SonarQube. Somehow I can see some bugs, code smells etc., except vulnerabilities.
I have installed "dependency-ckeck-sonar-plugin" in SonarQube and got the error "Dependency-Check report does not exist.". This also shows 0 vulnerabilities.

**sonar-project.properties**

```
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
sonar.projectKey=jest-sonar-reporter
sonar.projectName=applauncher-web
sonar.description=Angular SPA Frontend
sonar.verbose=true
sonar.projectVersion=7.3
sonar.sources=src/app
sonar.exclusions=/node_modules/,/dev/,/*.js,/.vb,**/.css,/*.scss
sonar.tests=src/app
sonar.test.inclusions=/*.unit.spec.ts
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath=reports/dependency-check-report.xml
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=reports/test-reporter.xml
sonar.genericcoverage.unitTestReportPaths=reports/test-reporter.xml
```

Note: I am using Angular6, TypeScript, and nodejs
any help please..